# Using a Telegram Bot, can a user trigger another user session of the bot?

Tags: javascript, api, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a big problem. I'm looking like a day to find a solution.

I created a Telegram Bot with the user sessions.

I need a user from his session to be able to update another user's session.

I have already tried to use a sendMessage from the session of the first user  which goes to send a message to the session of the second user. But I can't handle this message because, as I've seen, the bot.on() method only handle the message from the user, not from himself.

Any idea?

UPDATE 1:
Ok I think I have to give you more information.

There are 2 users. The 2nd user has a button. With the click of this button I want to run some logic on the session of the first user. At the moment with the click of the button I'm sending a msg in the session of the first user, but I can't trigger any logic.

Here the method inside the command triggered by clicking the button of the 2nd user:

```
bot.command('leave', async (ctx: MyContext)=>{
  try{
    await ServiceHelper.updateSession(ctx.session.chatId!, "");
    await ctx.api.sendMessage(ctx.session.chatId!, "The user left the conversation ", {reply_markup:{resize_keyboard: true, one_time_keyboard: true, keyboard: MenuChat.chatLeftMenu.build()} });
    ctx.session={
      ...ctx.session,
      chatId: "",
      step: "startMenu"
    }
    await MsgHandlerStart.managerStart(ctx);
  }
  catch(error){
    await ctx.answerCallbackQuery({text: ctx.i18n.t("answer-callback.wrong-command")});      
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by updating the session? Is that a field in the database or what?

Comment: I updated information on the post.  Btw yes, I want to update a field, the sessions of all the users are saved on a firestore db. But if I update the field in firebase the 2nd user has to do some action before get the update from the firebase db.

Comment: I feel like you should communicate between your sessions using an http api or with help of a database where you insert some events that the other session checks periodically.

Comment: Yes I used a value inside a db to check if the session changed. I think it's impossible my request.

Comment: It's possible if you write both bots in script but that's not a good thing to do. You need to have an API between both bots, whether a Database API or an HTTP API